# r - Count/percentage specific result per day

Tags: r, date

I have a dataset of about 15.000 observations spanning a couple of months.
Each date has a varying number of observations. 
The result of each observation is either "1" or "0".

```
Obs   Reslt  Date         ....
1     0      19-02-2017
2     1      19-02-2017
3     0      19-02-2017
4     0      19-02-2017
5     1      20-02-2017
6     1      20-02-2017
7     0      20-02-2017
8     0      20-02-2017
```

I would like to know the percentage of observation per day that have a result of "1".

In the example above the result would be:

```
19-02-2017 - 25%
20-02-2017 - 50%
```

I was wondering if someone could help me with this. 
Thank you!

Comment: `aggregate(Reslt ~ Date, df, FUN = mean)`

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is called `df` then

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  summarise(Perc = mean(Reslt)) %>%
  mutate(PercText = scales::percent(Perc))
```

**EDIT:** I've also included a second column `PercText` which has the percentage stored as text.

Comment: Don't forget to put `*100` since OP wants `25` and `50` as percentages

Comment: Thanks a lot! That gets me a long way.
However, r seems to see my dates in a wrong format. Do you know how I can force it in D-M-Y?

Comment: You can add the line `mutate(Date = as.Date(Date, "%d-%m-%Y")) %>%` between `df %>%` and  `group_by(Date) %>%`. That tells R that your column `Date` is actually a date with that specific format.

Answer (score 0):

```
library('scales') #useful in percent conversion
> dat
  Obs Reslt       Date
1   1     0 19-02-2017
2   2     1 19-02-2017
3   3     0 19-02-2017
4   4     0 19-02-2017
5   5     1 20-02-2017
6   6     1 20-02-2017
7   7     0 20-02-2017
8   8     0 20-02-2017
res <- aggregate(dat$Reslt, by=list(Date=dat$Date), FUN=mean) #calculate mean from each group of rows based on row values in column Date
res[,2] <- res[,2]*100 #small manipulation of data to get procentage 
res[,2] <- percent(res[,2] / 100)
>res
        Date   x
1 19-02-2017 25%
2 20-02-2017 50%
```

Comment: Hi! Some explanation would be useful for others finding this answer.